# How to show formally that for a random variable $X$, and $\epsilon>0$, that $X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|<\epsilon\}} < \epsilon^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I am wondering how I can show formally that for a random variable $X$, and $\epsilon>0$, that

$$
X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|<\epsilon\}} < \epsilon^2
$$

**My approach:**

$$
X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|<\epsilon\}}  = X^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{X^2<\epsilon^2\}}
$$

At this point, if I use reasoning by logic, we will have zero anytime $\epsilon^2 \geq X^2$. Then, we look at the case where $X^2 < \epsilon^2$. When this is $1$, $X^2$ may have value **at most** $\epsilon^2$.

**However,** I am wondering if someone has a more illuminating and more **rigorous** proof than the logical reasoning I used above. I would like a more rigorous proof as it can allow me to fully understand it from a structural perspective. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I think my answer may be a little more illuminating because I divide it into two cases, one where e > 1  and e^2 > e in that case. In the other case 0 < e < 1 and e > e^2>0. Both your argument and mine are rigorous.  But because the argument relies on this split mine could be considered more illuminating.  I don't think there is such a thing as more rigorous.  A proof is either rigorous or it isn't. A correct result is not rigorous if the argument is heuristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is rather trivial.  If $e > 1$ then $1 < e < e^2$ and $X^2 1_{\{|X|< e\}}$ is less than $e^2$ since the indicator function is zero otherwise. Note when $0 < |X| < e$ then $X^2 < e^2$ and the indicator function is not 0 there but the indicator function is otherwise 0.  If $0 < e < 1$ then $1 > e > e^2$ and the indicator function is 0 unless $0 < |X| < e < 1$ but this implies $X^2 < e^2$.